# Jquery/Jquery mobile - how to detect if a link clicked leads to an image or website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I'm trying to combine two JQM plugins and am stuck clearing out conflicts.

I have the following, which when clicked activates the [Photoswipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/) plugin:

```
<a class="swipeMe" href="../IMG/samples/166.png" rel="external"><img src="...
```

In the 2nd [splitview](http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/) plugin a clicked link with rel="external" fires the JQM HttpCleanup function:

```
httpCleanup = function(){
    window.setTimeout( function() { removeActiveLinkClass( true ); }, 200 );
    };
```

which gives me an "removeActiveLinkClass is not defined" error. The other error I'm getting is on closing Photoswipe, where firebug tells me "$.mobile._handleHashChange is not a function"

So I assume I need to add an if-clause that says: "if the link clicked is an image/not a webpage, skip the HTTPCleanup and don't do a hashChange".

How can I do this in Jquery or JqueryMobile?

**EDIT: more code..**

I think these are the relevant poritions of code

```
$(document).bind( "click", function(event) {

httpCleanup = function(){
    window.setTimeout( function() { removeActiveLinkClass( true ); }, 200 );
    };      

    var isExternal = useDefaultUrlHandling || ( $.mobile.path.isExternal( href ) && !isCrossDomainPageLoad );

    if( isExternal ) {           
   httpCleanup();
   //use default click handling
   return;
       }
```

Comment: could you show more code, how do you call the cleanup method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: $("a.swipeMe").attr("href"),
   complete: function(resp){
        ct = resp.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        }
   });
```

If `ct=="image/png"`, you have a PNG image.

Comment: isn't this overkill, should be carefull with where you put this piece of code, otherwise you will be fetching lots of urls only to see if their content type is that of an image.

Comment: He'd only need to use it as a test after the image was clicked -- so it only runs when it needs to run.

Comment: true, but out of context, if this is taken on some global selector, this would do some serious damage to the end-user's data limits :), just saying it should come with a note :)

Comment: I don't know if I want to use Ajax calls to do this. Since it's a mobile site, data limits will matter... I will put some more code in my question, maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Won't you be loading the content of the link after you click on it? So the ajax() call won't be loading anything that won't be loaded anyway, and the file should be cached, so no repeated downloads will take place. -- just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

you could just add a class to the anchor tags, when rendering them, and verify if it has that css class on it, in your cleanup function